# jquery validation plugin - reinitialize form after ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation plugin to validate some fields and using ajax to process.  Upon ajax success I am fading out the form div, reloading it (to get new updated values from the previous db update), and then fading it in.  My thought process for this is to show the new default values in the form as well as allow them to change again, and again, and so on if they wish.

Everything works, but on the reload/refresh of the form it will not allow for submission after the initial one.  I simply get my php processing page with an echo of "{"success":"success"}" which is my return for the ajax.

I realize this is because my form needs reinitialized, but everything I have tried will not do so.

On my main page I initialize the form with AccountProfile.init();... this does not work.  I have also tried handleInfo(); and this does not seem to work either.

Is it possible to reinitialize the form within itself per se in this manner?

```
var AccountProfile = function () {

    //ACCOUNT INFO FORM
    var handleInfo = function() {

        $('#account-info-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            rules: {
                fname: {
                    cname: true
                },
                lname: {
                    cname: true
                },
                email: {
                    cemail: true
                },
                timezone: {
                    required: true
                }
            },

            messages: {
                fname: {
                    cname: "Enter a valid first name."
                },
                lname: {
                    cname: "Enter a valid last name."
                },
                email: {
                    cemail: "Enter a valid email."
                },
                timezone: {
                    required: "Timezone is required."
                }
            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },

            unhighlight: function (element) { // un-hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.closest('.input-group'));
            },

            // ajax submit
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(form).attr('method'),
                    url: $(form).attr('action'),
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    dataType : 'json'
                }).done(function (response) {
                    if (response.success == 'success') {

                        $('#account-info-form').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            $('#account-info-form').load('/account/ #account-info-form', function() {
                                $('#account-info-form').fadeIn('slow');
                                // show success toast
                                toastr.info('Your profile has been updated.', 'Updated!');
                                // reinitialize form
                                AccountProfile.init();
                            });
                        });

                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        // show error toast
                        toastr.error('An error has occurred. &nbsp;Please contact support.', 'Error!')
                    }
                });
                return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
            }
        });

        // custom email validation
        $.validator.addMethod("cemail", function (value,element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(value);
        },"Please enter a valid email.");

        // custom name (first or last) validation
        $.validator.addMethod("cname", function (value,element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z][a-z .,\-]{0,31}$|^$/i.test(value);
        },"Please enter a valid name.");

        // return default values on blank and do not cause error (if valid)
        $('input[data-default="true"]').on('blur', function() {
            if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
                $(this).val( this.defaultValue );
                $(this).valid();
            }
        });

    }




    //ACCOUNT PASSWORD FORM
    var handlePassword = function() {
    }

    //ACCOUNT PRIVACY FORM
    var handlePrivacy = function() {
    }


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            handleInfo();
            handlePassword();
            handlePrivacy();
        }
    };

}();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason... everything works properly if the fading and loading is performed on a wrapper outside of the actual form rather than the form ID itself.  Perhaps someone can explain this.

```
$('#tab_account_info').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#tab_account_info').load('/account/ #tab_account_info', function() {
        $('#tab_account_info').fadeIn('slow');

        // reinitializes the form and core handlers
        AccountProfile.init();
        App.initAjax();

        // show success toast
        toastr.info('Your profile has been updated.', 'Updated!');
    })
});
```